# Browserify tiny-secp256k1

Tags: javascript, browserify, secp256k1

I am trying to use [tiny-secp256k1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-secp256k1) in a Javascript project. I would like the code to be compatible with Node.js and the browser, the require modules in the index file are:

```
const createHmac = require('create-hmac')
const ecc = require('tiny-secp256k1')
```

**Browserify** does not have problems with *create-hmac* but for *tiny-secp256k1* I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'tiny-secp256k1'
```

In the github repo, [there are some examples of the library used in a react app.](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/tiny-secp256k1/tree/master/examples/react-app) But I dont know how it works.

Is it possible to use this library in the browser?